# awk match and find mismatch between files and output results

Tags: awk

In the below `awk` I am using `$5` `$7` and `$8` of `file1` to search `$3` `$5` and `$6` of `file2`. The header row is skipped and it then outputs a new file with what lines match and if they do not match what `file` the match is missing from. When I search for one match use 3 fields for the key for the lookup and do not skip the header I get `current output`.  I apologize for the long post and `file examples`, just trying to include everything to help get this working.  Thank you :).

**file1**

```
 Index  Chromosomal Position    Gene    Inheritance Start   End Ref Alt Func.refGene
98  48719928    FBN1    AD  48719928    48719929    AT  -   exonic
101 48807637    FBN1    AD  48807637    48807637    C   T   exonic
```

**file2**

```
R_Index Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.IDP.refGene
36  chr15   48719928    48719929    AT  -   exonic
37  chr15   48719928    48719928    A   G   exonic
38  chr15   48807637    48807637    C   T   exonic
```

**awk**

```
awk -F'\t' '
    NR == FNR {
            A[$25]; A[$26]; A[$27]
            next
    }
    {
            B[$3]; B[$5]; B[$6]
    }
    END {
            print "Match"
            OFS=","
            for ( k in A )
            {
                    if ( k && k in B )
                            printf "%s ", k
            }

            print "Missing from file1"
            OFS=","
            for ( k in B )
            {
                    if ( ! ( k in A ) )
                            printf "%s ", k
            }

            print "Missing from file2"
            OFS=","
            for ( k in A )
            {
                    if ( ! ( k in B ) )
                            printf "%s ", k
            }
    }
' file1 file2 > list
```

**current output**

```
Match
Missing from file1
A C Ref 48807637 Alt Start T G - AT 48719928 Missing from file2
```

**desired output**

```
Match 48719928 AT -, 48807637 C T
Missing from file1 48719928 A G
Missing from file2
```

Comment: remove the space between the array elements

Comment: Removing the space did allow the `awk` to run, but the output is not correct (seems to be one file with the original data in it and some additional data).... I posted it as an edit.  Thank you :).

Comment: What does `current output 1` represent? Your script has syntax errors, it can't be producing any output. What does `Edit` represent? Just show a [mcve] with clear, concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Program 1

This works, except the output format is different from what you request:

```
awk 'FNR==1 { next }
     FNR == NR { file1[$5,$7,$8] = $5 " " $7 " " $8 }
     FNR != NR { file2[$3,$5,$6] = $3 " " $5 " " $6 }
     END { print "Match:"; for (k in file1) if (k in file2) print file1[k] # Or file2[k]
           print "Missing in file1:"; for (k in file2) if (!(k in file1)) print file2[k]
           print "Missing in file2:"; for (k in file1) if (!(k in file2)) print file1[k]
     }' file1 file2
```

#### Output 1

```
Match:
48807637 C T
48719928 AT -
Missing in file1:
48719928 A G
Missing in file2:
```

#### Program 2

If you must have each set of values in a category comma-separated on a single line, then:

```
awk 'FNR==1 { next }
     FNR == NR { file1[$5,$7,$8] = $5 " " $7 " " $8 }
     FNR != NR { file2[$3,$5,$6] = $3 " " $5 " " $6 }
     END {
            printf "Match"
            pad = " "
            for (k in file1)
            {
                if (k in file2)
                {
                    printf "%s%s", pad, file1[k]
                    pad = ", "
                }
            }
            print ""

            printf "Missing in file1"
            pad = " "
            for (k in file2)
            {
                if (!(k in file1))
                {
                    printf "%s%s", pad, file2[k]
                    pad = ", "
                }
            }
            print ""

            printf "Missing in file2"
            pad = " "
            for (k in file1)
            {
                if (!(k in file2))
                {
                    printf "%s%s", pad, file1[k]
                    pad = ", "
                }
            }
            print ""
     }' file1 file2
```

The code is a little bigger, but the format used exacerbates the difference.  The change is all in the END block; the other code is unchanged.  The sequences of actions in the END block no longer fit comfortably on a single line, so they're spread out for readability.  You can apply a liberal smattering of semicolons and concatenate the lines to shrink the apparent size of the program if you desire.

It's tempting to try a function for the printing, but the conditions just make it too tricky to be worthwhile, I think — but I'm open to persuasion otherwise.

#### Output 2

```
Match 48807637 C T, 48719928 AT -
Missing in file1 48719928 A G
Missing in file2
```

This output will be a lot harder to parse than the one shown first, so doing anything automatically with it will be tricky.  While there are only 3 entries to worry about, the line length isn't an issue.  If you get to 3 million entries, the lines become very long and unmanageable.

Comment: Thank you all for your help and explanations, I really appreciate them :) @Jonathan Leffler program 1 works great :)

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand awk syntax and are confusing awk with shell. When you wrote:

```
A[$25] [$26] [$27]
```

you probably meant:

```
A[$25]; A[$26]; A[$27]
```

(and similarly for `B[]`) and when you wrote:

```
IFS=
```

since `IFS` is a shell variable, not an awk one, you maybe meant

```
FS=
```

BUT since you're doing that in the `END` section and not calling `split()` and so not doing anything that would use `FS` idk what you were hoping to achieve with that. Maybe you meant:

```
OFS=
```

BUT you aren't doing anything that would use `OFS` and your desired output isn't comma-separated so idk what you'd be hoping to achieve with that either.

If that's not enough info for you to solve your problem yourself then reduce your example to something with 10 columns or less so we don't have to read a lot of irrelevant info to help you.

Comment: I cleaned up the post and the 'awk' does run now (I was confusing `awk syntax with shell`).  The only output is what results and I took out the `edit`.  Thank you very much :).

Comment: You're welcome. Now just change your `print k`s to `printf "%s ", k`s and you're almost done. Do that then let us know if you need more help.

Comment: I updated the post with the output, what does the `printf "%s ", k` do?  Thank you :).

Comment: specify a comma be printed separated multiple strings.  Thank you for all your help :).

Comment: You're welcome but no, it doesn't say that. I recommend you read the book Effecitve Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins if you're going to be learning to use awk, it'll save you a lot of time on trial and error and is an excellent reference to have handy.